# Mongdb query multiple value in different docs

Tags: mongodb

How could query multiple value in one collection?

```
const user = db.collection('users').findOne({ username: 'john' })
const user = db.collection('users').findOne({ email: 'mail@gmail.com' })
```

Below are some dummy data. i hope could query name john and email docs in one line of code.

```
[{id:1, username: 'john', email: 'john@mail.com'},{id:2, username: 'kelvin', email: 'mail@gmail.com'}, {id:3, username: 'angle', email: 'angle@gmail.com'}]
```

Return Data Are:  only id: 1 and 2. becasue they match the query

```
    [{id:1, username: 'john', email: 'john@mail.com'},{id:2, username: 'kelvin', email: 'mail@gmail.com'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator in this way:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "username": "john"
    },
    {
      email: "mail@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
})
```

So you will find a document which matches `username` or `email`.

Exmaple [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/anzmK_eujMi)

Comment: Oh! Thanks you! It is what i look for =)